# Better way to parse a string array into a map in eclipse collections

Tags: java, collections

Is there a better way of parsing an array of strings delimited by `'='` into a map.

```
MutableMap<String, String> config = new UnifiedMap<>();
      ArrayIterate.collectWith(data.split(","), String::split, "=")
                  .each(v -> config.put(v[0], v[1]));
```

Comment: That are your criteria for better?

Comment: Can you show example input?

Comment: @stephen-c - better as in simpler, toMap() as suggested by Donald below does the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if the following will match your input, but I assume it is probably similar structurally based on your two calls to split.  You can use `toMap` to simplify the code slightly instead of constructing the `UnifiedMap` and using `each`.

This solution uses `ArrayIterate` as you have above:

```
String data = "1=one,2=two,3=three";

MutableMap<String, String> config =
        ArrayIterate.collectWith(data.split(","), String::split, "=")
                .toMap(a -> a[0], a -> a[1]);
```

This solution uses an `ArrayAdapter`, which may make the code easier to read depending on your criteria for better.

```
MutableMap<String, String> config = ArrayAdapter.adapt(data.split(","))
        .collectWith(String::split, "=")
        .toMap(a -> a[0], a -> a[1]);
```

Using ArrayAdapter will make it possible for you to make the call to collectWith() lazy instead of eager, which may be beneficial if your comma-separated array has a lot of data.

```
MutableMap<String, String> config = ArrayAdapter.adapt(data.split(","))
        .asLazy()
        .collectWith(String::split, "=")
        .toMap(a -> a[0], a -> a[1]);
```

You can also use `Arrays.stream()` with `Collectors2` available in EC, but then you can't use the method reference with `map` as you have with `collectWith`.

```
MutableMap<String, String> config = Arrays.stream(data.split(","))
        .map(string -> string.split("="))
        .collect(Collectors2.toMap(a -> a[0], a -> a[1]));
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense.